# How to expose Hystrix jmx for Prometheus

Tags: hystrix, prometheus

I'm new to Hystrix and I just created my first Hystrix Commands. The commands are being created and executed in a loop so the metrics data should have being registered. I am using the servo metrics publisher as follows:

```
HystrixPlugins.getInstance()
    .registerMetricsPublisher(HystrixServoMetricsPublisher.getInstance());
```

**EDIT:**
Looking at the JConsole I found the related metrics definition as follows in the link:

[jconsole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vh6Vl.png)

I am not using spring, eureka, servo to read data and run the app.

I would like to know how to expose this data in a way that prometheus can read. I tried [hystrix-prometheus](https://github.com/soundcloud/prometheus-hystrix), but the documentation is not helpful when it is about where the metrics are being exposed, how to get them or check the them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve Hystrix metrics, you'll first need to get [Prometheus' Java Simple Client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_java) up and running. The setup depends on your environment. Independent of your environment the result should be a URL where you can retrieve i.e. simple Java metrics.

Once that it up and running, you can use the line

```
HystrixPrometheusMetricsPublisher.register("application_name");
```

to register the additional Hystrix metrics. They will be served by the same URL. Please note that you will see Hystrix metrics only after the first call of a Hystrix enabled command.

Comment: Thanks ahus1! That helped me.